# Intent dependendent on 2 API calls?

Tags: android, android-async-http

Suppose I have a situation where an API response fills my Musician model with information specific to that musician.  There is another API response that, given a musician name, describes related artists.

I want to launch a detail activity showing the musician's name, members, genre, albums(API response A) along with related artists(API response B).

An asynchronous network call will provide a better user experience, but since launching the detail activity is dependent on 2 different api calls, is there a better solution than having API call be asynch and API call B be synch(blocking A and the UI)?

If I make both asynchronous, API call B could be running while the activity changes, stopping it(since an asynctask is destroyed when the activity changes).  This would result in missing data in the detail activity.

Answer (score 0):

In a simple case:

1. Start the detail activity
2. Execute both requests asynchronously while presenting the user with a loading UX
3. Once is retrieved, update the UI accordingly

   - You can change the *layout* of an `Activity` at any time at runtime without recreating it.
   - You can either update the UI immediately with "Response A" and then again with "Response B" or wait for both responses to return and then update the UI; the former is preferable.

Network operations should **never** block the UI or the user. Displaying loading spinners and such is perfectly acceptable and is used all the time in Google's own apps.